# Configuration change after nuget packages update

Tags: package, nuget, app-config

I have updated nuget packages in my project.

In my app.config files I received new dependent assemblies which were absent before. For example:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.2.0" newVersion="5.6.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I removed all new dependencies to make app.configuration looks similar to what was before nuget update (changed only updated dependent assembly, without adding new ones)...
But appears that with new nuget packages, I actually need new dependentAssembly set, but I removed them and can't remember which ones should be added.

Is there a way to somehow refresh dependentAssembly in app.config? Hopefully without removing and adding nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following command on each of the packages where you removed the dependent versions

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>
```

Have a read at this [Doc](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages) though to be sure you don't make things worse. Based on the information you provided it should be straightforward for you